# Django-compressor & S3 Boto: Static files not compressed

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto3, django-compressor

### The Error

The static files are saved in S3 - however they are not compressed.

### My Code

**HTML**

```
{% compress css %}
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/project.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
{% endcompress %}
```

**Production settings**

```py
COMPRESS_ENABLED = True
STATICFILES_STORAGE = '<myproject>.storage.CachedS3Boto3Storage'
COMPRESS_STORAGE = STATICFILES_STORAGE
COMPRESS_URL = STATIC_URL
COMPRESS_FILTERS = {
    'css': ['compressor.filters.css_default.CssAbsoluteFilter'],
    'js': ['compressor.filters.jsmin.JSMinFilter']
}
```

**CachedS3BotoStorage**

```py
from django.core.files.storage import get_storage_class
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage


class CachedS3Boto3Storage(S3Boto3Storage):
    """
    S3 storage backend that saves the files locally, too.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CachedS3Boto3Storage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.local_storage = get_storage_class(
            "compressor.storage.CompressorFileStorage")()

    def save(self, name, content):
        self.local_storage._save(name, content)
        super(CachedS3Boto3Storage, self).save(name, self.local_storage._open(name))
        return name
```

### What is recommended

The [docs](https://django-compressor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote-storages/) show you'll end up with something like this -

```py
STATIC_ROOT = '/path/to/staticfiles'
COMPRESS_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'mysite.storage.CachedS3BotoStorage'
COMPRESS_STORAGE = STATICFILES_STORAGE
STATIC_URL = 'https://compressor-test.s3.amazonaws.com/'
COMPRESS_URL = STATIC_URL
```

**What I can confirm**

- My `COMPRESS_ROOT` & `STATIC_ROOT` are the same : `'/app/staticfiles'`
- `STATICFILES_STORAGE` is pointing  at `<myproject>.storage.CachedS3BotoStorage`
- STATIC_URL is `'https://s3.amazonaws.com/<my_prod-bucket>/static/'`
- COMPRESS_URL == STATIC_URL

### Ideas?

Any ideas why compressor isn't compressing?

EDIT: this implementation is messing with Django Debug Toolbar so it seems like using `{{ STATIC_URL }}` in the static file paths "works" but at the same time the settings are then screwing up the debug toolbar.